# Trying to POST data using ajax but seems to break when adding some string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The script can send data successfully without login_sql variable.

Can post data with

```
data:{studentID:studentID, password:password}
```

This one posts successfully, but when added to the SQL part, the post fails.

```
var studentID = $("#studentID").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var login_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE studentID = '"+studentID+"' AND password = '"+password+"'";
            //alert(login_sql);

            if($.trim(studentID).length >0 & $.trim(password).length >0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",  //Request type
                    url: "http://example.com",   
                    data:{studentID:studentID, password:password, login_sql:'SELECT * FROM users WHERE studentID ='+studentID+' AND password='+password},
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if(data != ""){
                            window.location.replace('student_info.html'); 
                        }else{
                            alert("No response from the server.");
                        }
                    },
```

Want to post the sql to the server with the ajax script

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is an extremely bad idea as anyone with a decent browser can see the JavaScript and change it to do whatever they want, including getting login details of others and anything else you happen to have stored in that database.

Comment: I know and understand the security issues, but that is not a big concern right now.

Answer (score 2):

You are not escaping your sql string correctly:

```
{studentID:studentID, password:password, login_sql:"SELECT * FROM users WHERE studentID ='"+studentID+"' AND password='"+password+"'"}
```

saying that, this is a very dangerous query as you are exposing your databse and will be prone to SQL injecion

Comment: Thank you @vincent Chinner for your input. I have tried so, but it's still not working. I also thought that was the issue but not working after rectifying it.

Comment: @Abiudeko might be a server side issue